# Updating old plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm updating a plugin that is very old and no longer maintained.  The long and short is that the the old developer is defunct and this plugin was custom created for a client.  In Wordpress with debug mode on I'm seeing several of the following message, only after enabling this plugin, which leads me to believe this deprecated plugin is the culprit.

> Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since
>   version 2.0.0! Usage of user levels is deprecated. Use capabilities
>   instead. in
>   /home3/oodzopmy/public_html/sitename/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   4045

Unfortunately when I go hunting in the various code I'm unable to locate `has_cap` anywhere.  Is there a way I can locate the offending code that is calling `has_cap` behind the scenes?

Comment: You can use String Locator plugin, it will find the string you search for in the specified directory

Comment: Research here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=has_cap+deprecated+is%3Aq

Comment: It is not really an answer so I post it as a comment. You can download the entire site and open the directory in an editor like Atom or Sublime Text. You then can search the whole project for "has_cap"